# How do I assign counter?

Tags: transactions

I know that counter is always incremented by 1, but what I don't understand is how to get the initial value of counter for an account.

Comment: You can get the counter value from [RPC](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-counter), if it's been initalized. You can not however assign it yourself, it gets incremented itself to prevent replay attack.

Comment: thanks Tomas, I think I understand.

Comment: could you please post as an answer @TomášZemanovič ? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can get the counter value from [RPC](https://tezos.gitlab.io/mainnet/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-contracts-contract-id-counter), if it's been initialized. You can not however assign it yourself, it gets incremented itself to prevent replay attack.